# Shrink Volume of Bitlocker Encrypted Drive on Windows 11

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, bitlocker, windows-11

Windows 11 had allowed me to use its built in disk management tool to “shrink volume” of a bitlocker encrypted drive. This drive does not contain the operating system.

From some searching on the web, it appears that previously this option was grayed out and not available until bitlocker encryption is turned off. However Windows 11 had allowed me to do so. I now have an unallocated partition. Is this an error? Or did Windows 11 manage to properly divide the partitions?

I had later turned off Bitlocker encryption on the original partition. I have yet to allocate this new partition.

Am I safe to use this new partition or is it highly likely to overwrite files that were supposed to remain on the original encrypted partition?

Comment: Where did you read it wasn’t possible to shrink a BitLocker protected volume? If the encrypted volume still exists what exactly is your question?

Comment: My guess is that was a bug.

Comment: As far as I know Windows prevents writing or reading after the end of a partition. So if the partition information is properly updated and Windows uses it's own system for accessing the partition and not the whole drive than there is no way to overwrite data that lies outside of the boundaries the partition.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using that new partition by installing Ubuntu alongside Windows. I did not observe any issues.

Answer (score -1):

I personally disabled my bitlocker on the new drive that I had made, basically disabling both drives. Once the bitlocker was done doing its thing , I went ahead and deleted the new drive that was encrypted,which had nothing on it, and deleted that real quick, and then turn back on bitlocker... I was stunned that it happened! I was disappointed to find out I had 2 encrypted drives, with 2 long keywords, but saved it just in case.
But I don't know, I don't want to ever experience this again, but it happens.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1113469)